# How to Implement transaction in function for an XML file?

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am passing an XML file to my function. I am making insert/update query for some xmlElements. After executing that query on database,immediatly I will update
those xmlElements.Next I will move to another xmlElement . Now I want to implement transaction for this function.
 Because if any insertion/updateion fails for any xmlElement in middle of that xml file, I want to roll back all my changes in that xml file.

I want to rollback changes in database and in my xml file.

How can I implement transaction for this function?

Thanks & Regards,
SJN.